# from thrust to arrayfire - gfor usage?

Tags: cuda, thrust, arrayfire

I am trying to replace some thrust calls to arrayfire to check the performance.

I am not sure if I am using properly arrayfire because the results I am taking do not match at all.

So , the thrust code for example I am using is:

```
cudaMalloc( (void**) &devRow, N * sizeof(float) );
...//devRow is filled

thrust::device_ptr<float> SlBegin( devRow );
for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++, SlBegin += PerSlElmts )
{
    thrust::inclusive_scan( SlBegin, SlBegin + PerSlElmts, SlBegin );
}

cudaMemcpy( theRow, devRow, N * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );
//use theRow...
```

Arrayfire:

```
af::array SlBegin( N , devRow );
for ( int i = 0;i < N; i++,SlBegin += PerSlElmts )
{
    accum( SlBegin );
}

cudaMemcpy( theRow, devRow, N * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );
//use theRow..
```

I am not sure how arrayfire handles the copy : `af::array SlBegin( N , devRow );` .In thrust we have the device pointer which points from devRow to SlBegin , but in arrayfire..?

Also , I wanted to ask about using gfor .
In [arrayfire webpage](http://www.arrayfire.com/docs/page_gfor.htm)  , it states that

> Do not use this function directly; see GFOR: Parallel For-Loops.

And then for GFOR :

> GFOR is disabled in the current version of ArrayFire

So , we can't use gfor?

---------UPDATE---------------------------

I have a small running example which shows the different results:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <curand_kernel.h>

#include "arrayfire.h"

#include <thrust/scan.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>

__global__ void Kernel( const int N ,float * const devRow )
{

   int i = threadIdx.x;
   if ( i < N )
        devRow[ i ] = i;

 }

int main(){

    int N = 6;
    int Slices = 2;
    int PerSlElmts = 3;

    float * theRow = (float*) malloc ( N * sizeof( float ));

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i ++ )
        theRow[ i ] = 0;

    // raw pointer to device memory
    float * devRow;
    cudaMalloc( (void **) &devRow, N * sizeof( float ) );

    Kernel<<< 1,N >>>( N , devRow );
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    // wrap raw pointer with a device_ptr
    thrust::device_ptr<float> SlBegin( devRow );

    for ( int i = 0; i < Slices; i++ , SlBegin += PerSlElmts )
        thrust::inclusive_scan( SlBegin, SlBegin + PerSlElmts , SlBegin );

    cudaMemcpy( theRow, devRow, N * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
        printf("\n Thrust accum : %f",theRow[ i ] );


    //--------------------------------------------------------------------//
    Kernel<<< 1,N >>>( N , devRow );
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    af::array SlBeginFire( N, devRow );

    for ( int i = 0; i < Slices; i++ , SlBeginFire += PerSlElmts )
        af::accum( SlBeginFire );

    SlBeginFire.host( theRow );

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
            printf("\n Arrayfire accum : %f",theRow[ i ] );

    cudaFree( devRow );
    free( theRow );


    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to run a column-wise (0th-dim in ArrayFire) scan on a 2D array. Here is some code that you could use:

```
af::array SlBegin(N, devRow);
af::array result = accum(SlBegin, 0);
```

Here is a sample output

```
A [5 3 1 1]
0.7402     0.4464     0.7762 
0.9210     0.6673     0.2948 
0.0390     0.1099     0.7140 
0.9690     0.4702     0.3585 
0.9251     0.5132     0.6814 

accum(A, 0) [5 3 1 1]
0.7402     0.4464     0.7762 
1.6612     1.1137     1.0709 
1.7002     1.2236     1.7850 
2.6692     1.6938     2.1435 
3.5943     2.2070     2.8249
```

This runs and inclusive scan on each column independently.

As for gfor, it has been added to the Open Source version of ArrayFire. As this code base is still a beta, improvements and fixes are taking place very rapidly. So keep a watch on our github page.

Comment: :Hello and thanks for helping.Can you please write the analogous piece of code , as I have it?Is it necessary to use another array ( result ) fro the accum or not?After the loop do I have to do SlBegin.host( theRow );?Can you please provide me with this example?I am using a 1D ,not 2D array.

Comment: The code you have shown suggests the wrong use of ArrayFire. I would suggest you to post on the ArrayFire mailing list https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/arrayfire-users if you want to discuss your code.